# GORM querying: findAllByPropertyNotInList or findByPropertyNotInList do not exist, any equivalency?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

The next code works:

```
self query1 = DomainClassExample.findAllByPropertyInList("hi","bye")
```

But if I add **Not**, <strike>the dynamic finder does not exist</strike> (it DOES exists: check the answer):

```
self query2 = DomainClassExample.findAllByPropertyNotInList("hi","bye")
```

I want to get all the DomainClassExample which don't have the property "hi" or "bye". Is there any dynamic finder for that purpose? Should I use the Where Query. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Grails 1.3.9, given the following domain:

```
class User {
    String username
    ....
}
```

this works in our application without any issues:

```
def userList = User.findAllByUsernameNotInList(["user1@testdomain.com","user2@anotherdomain.com"])
```

Comment: You are right. I thought it was not correct because my IDE (eclipse) paints differently `findAllByPropertyInList` than `findAllByPropertyNotInList`. Thank you! :)

Comment: I feel your pain!  I've recently switched to IntelliJ and have been impressed with how much better it does with these things.

Answer (score 1):

First, a minor correction.  It's not a method expression.  It's a dynamic finder. Now, as to your actual problem, you'll need to use the criteria API for this...

```
def c = DomainClassExample.createCriteria()
def matchingProperties = c.list {
    property {
        not { 'in'(["hi","bye"]) }
    }
}
```

You might run into an issue with the word '`property`' and I haven't actually tested the code I just wrote.  But that is the gist of it.